# how to ignore folder when using adb push

Tags: adb

I like to copy development files (ie a git repo) from my local machine to my android using adb push (I still couldn't find a reliable git client application on android).

However, I also need to ignore certain directories (think of the directories that are typically ignored by git and placed in .gitignore).. such as the build folder in a java project.

How do I make an adb push command that ignores a certain directory but copies everything else?

Comment: Afraid not at all unless writing a script walking the tree recursively and skip them as you defined.

Comment: Isn't there a reliable free (or even paid!) Android git client? I find this embarrassing

Comment: The only free one coming to my mind is [MGit](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.manichord.mgit/), if paid ones are acceptable maybe also [Pocket Git](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.pocketgit). If you want a command-line variant, [Termux](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/) would be the way to go (you can install git from within Termux). As I'm not using any such client I cannot tell how reliable they are.

Comment: I use Termux a lot and it's very reliable. Must give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an XY problem as excluding files and directories with `adb push` isn't what you're really intending to do.

If you're syncing Git repositories, the best option is a Git client. The one I'm currently using is [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) and I do a lot of development on my phone with it.

Download Termux and use its built-in APT package manager to install Git and you'll be able to process your work easily.